# Which templates files are used for PrestaShop product and category pages?

Tags: file, task-parallel-library, prestashop

Which tpl file is used for individual product page in prestashop.
and which tpl file for products listing.
I have tried searching google but dint get any answer.

Comment: You don't need to search Google: find a unique ID of an element in product page, then search all the prestashop files for this ID/element.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in your themes folder,

```
yoursite/themes/yourtheme/product.tpl for product 
yoursite/themes/yourtheme/product-list.tpl for list of product
yoursite/themes/yourtheme/category.tpl the category info over the product page list
```

Comment: hi @Fil0z0 i forgot to thank you for the reply. And thanks for the reply. I also need help in other query which css files are used for products lissting page n individual product page. please reply thank you.

Comment: Hi yoursite/themes/yourtheme/css/product-list.css for product list and product.css for page product